# facebook posting link multiple times seems not to work

Tags: facebook, hyperlink

I have found that if a user posts a few links via 'whats on your mind' or graph api link publish that only the first 1-2 will show on their friends news feed. After a couple within an hour, no further link publishes appear in the friends area.

Secondly, i have notice that if you have 3 friends a -> friend -> b -> friend c that if a publishes a link, b sees it (except in the case above) and if b clicks 'Share' you would think that c should see it in their news feed. they do NOT at all.  Note, this is using facebooks own 'whats on your mind' widget.

Should I log these as a bug, the 2nd is particularly concerning as links dont share. If its the graph/edge rank, then it appears that posting someone elses link doesnt have much ranking ? why isnt it just like posting your own link.  even that seems to fail after a couple..

Comment: thanks, it makes sense. However, in the 2nd case for sharing, the 3 friends are not all friends a is a friend of b and b of c. if a shares a link it shows in b's feed. now if b sees it and hits 'share' and shares it with their friends, why doesnt it show up in c's news feed. it actually seens to never show in c's feed. only 1st shares are reliable. is this a possible bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook groups and filters content based on a variety of factors.

If someone is posting dozens of links from your site it's logical that they would stop showing up with any visibility in other user's feeds as the links have effectively become spam. After a period of time [short for a few links, long for many] things reset but if it's persistent you can see a page banned.

There's no bug in that, it's the intended functionality to keep Facebook relevant.

As far as sharing, again, Facebook will try to group similar items together and in the case of 3 people who are all friends already, this generally results in a single "story" with two individual "comments". If there are no comments with the share I'm not sure Facebook passes the activity along if the user has already seen the story.

Comment: thanks, it makes sense. However, in the 2nd case for sharing, the 3 friends are not all friends a is a friend of b and b of c. if a shares a link it shows in b's feed.  now if b sees it and hits 'share' and shares it with their friends, why doesnt it show up in c's news feed. it actually seens to never show in c's feed. only 1st shares are reliable. is this a possible bug ?